# On measurable functions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, measurable-functions

It is known pretty well that a measurable function on $[0,1]$ need not be equal almost everywhere to a continuous function. The standard example one uses for this, that is the indicator function of $[0,1/2]$, however, happens to be continuous almost everywhere. Hence, I would like to know of an example of a measurable function on $[0,1]$ that cannot be equal almost everywhere to an almost everywhere continuous function on $[0,1]$. Any help shall be immensely appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicator on a fat Cantor set?

Comment: Yes,that should do it,thanks.

Comment: I would like to have a few more properties,though.Shall be posting in a separate question shortly.